# TCP View - Two versions of Computer Name listed under 'Local Address' column. Explanation?

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter, tcp

When I open TCPView I always get two versions of various core system processes (Ex. LSASS.exe, Services.exe, Wininit.exe).

The versions are differentiated by the Computer Name listed under the **Local Address** column of TCPView.

So, for example, assuming the Computer Name is "Bigcomp" the two versions of the name will always be "Bigcomp" and "bigcomp". One is capital-letter-sensitive the other does not feature any capital letters I included in the computer's name.

Is it normal to always have two versions of core system and network processes listed here? Why is one case-sensitive and the other not?

Should this be concerning?

Comment: My guess is you've got a a IPv4 connection and a IPv6 connection that a resolving to different names.

Comment: Press **Ctrl+R** to see the resolved or unresolved IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> Should this be concerning?

**No.** Some processes will listen or make connections via both TCP/IP v4 and v6, so two such entries are not a problem.

Further, computer names (e.g. NetBIOS, DNS) expose no functional difference for use of different case, so a connection made to/from `MyHost` and `MYHOST` both refer to the same host. The case displayed to the user is purely cosmetic, though by convention NetBIOS names are always uppercase.